# How to use a dynamic expression for a value in an Entity Framework select clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

I'm not sure if I'm asking this question correctly, or in an understandable way, but here it goes:

I'm trying to figure out a dynamic way to set a value within a select from a database context. I'm using something I call a CodeTableValuePOCO in over a hundred places throughout my code, and I don't want to specify the whole expression every time I need it (especially the syntax for finding the `CodeName` value). So, I tried with an expression like this, to generate it dynamically.

```
internal static Expression<Func<CodeTableValue, CodeTableValuePOCO>> GetCodeTableValueSelectorExpression(int languageId) {
        return x => new CodeTableValuePOCO
        {
            Code = x.Code,
            // Check if there are any translations for the code name
            CodeName = x.Translations != null
                        // If there are, check if there is a translation for user's language
                        ? x.Translations.LanguageTranslationTexts.Count(t => t.Language_ID == languageId) > 0
                            // If there is a translation, take the first for the given language
                            ? x.Translations.LanguageTranslationTexts.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Language_ID == languageId).Text
                            // Else, default to codeName
                            : x.CodeName
                        // Else, default to codeName
                        : x.CodeName,
            CodeTableId = x.CodeTable.CodeTableID,
            Id = x.CodeTableValueID,
            Key = x.CodeTable.Key,
            ParentId = x.ParentID
        };
    }
```

But, I can't figure out how to use the above expression in my code. I think it would work if I only was looking for a `CodeTableValuePOCO`
, but the `CodeTableValuePOCO` is embedded in larger selects, like the example below. It's not working, obviously, since the program is expecting a CodeTableValuePOCO, but getting an Expression.

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext()) {

    return db.Notifications
        .Where(x => x.id == 1)        
        .Select(x => new NotificationPOCO
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Message = x.Message,
            //This part is, obviously, not working
            Type = code.GetCodeTableValueSelectorExpression(2)
         })
         .ToList();
        }
}
```

Comment: Is it really `code.GetCodeTableValueSelectorExpression(2)` - i.e. it doesn't depend on each row that you're selecting? If so, it can be easily lifted out as a pre-calculated value (yes it may mean two round trip DB calls but until you see this causing an actual performance issue I wouldn't be too concerned about it).  On the other than, if `GetCodeTableValueSelectorExpression( )` is an inner query that must be performed for each record being selected, there's a few ways you can go about it of varying complexity, including building up expression trees manually.

Comment: BTW assuming you do mean the latter, have you tried doing just `x.CodeTables.Select( GetCodeTableValueSelectorExpression(2) )` to see if that much works?

Comment: Thanks, but no, it's a single codeTableValue, not a collection, but, there can be thousands of the parent item, so I can't have it be two separate queries.

Comment: I'm still a little confused - as written, `GetCodeTableValueSelectorExpression()` returns an expression for a function that takes a `CodeTableValue`, but in your example you're not actually trying to call the function that's returned - assuming you were, where is the CodeTableValue parameter coming from? If it's not something that is different for each row in your parent query, then it can definitely be lifted out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no natural C# compile time support for using expressions inside other expressions.

You need some expression composition library - for instance, [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit). It explains the problem and addresses it with custom `Invoke` and `AsExpandable` extension methods. The solution in your case is something like this (after installing the package):

```
using LinqKit;

using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext()) {
    var codeTableValueSelector = GetCodeTableValueSelectorExpression(2); 
    return db.Notifications.AsExpandable()
        .Where(x => x.id = 1)        
        .Select(x => new NotificationPOCO
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Message = x.Message,
            Type = codeTableValueSelector.Invoke(x) // or x.CodeTable? not sure from the sample code
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: That looks like what I want. I have Microsoft's DynamicLibrary installed (System.Linq.Dynamic). Do you know if I can do something similar within that?

Comment: Probably you can. But I can't recall the syntax (if any) - it's quite unusual as you know. You have to generate select string with quite unusual syntax to get it parsed and eventually processed. Wait.. now I remember you cannot do `new NotificationPOCO` with dynamic LINQ.

Comment: I tried LinqKit, but got this: 
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'BLL.POCO.CodeTableValuePOCO Invoke[CodeTableValue,CodeTableValuePOCO](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[BLL.POCO.CodeTableValuePOCO]], DAL.Models.CodeTableValue)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Did you add `AsExpandable` as in my sample? It's needed to actually post process the query expression tree and replace `Invoke` method.

Comment: YES! That worked! Thank you so much. I've been tearing my hair over this. BTW, what does AsExpandable do?

Comment: It's explained in the link (the LINQKit page). Basically creates a custom `IQueryable<T>` implementation which allows it to modify the query expression before passing it to the original (EF) query provider for execution.

Comment: Turns out the LinqKit queries slows down my queries significantly. Any remedies to that?

Comment: Hmm, this is the first time I hear something like that. Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: No, my mistake. It was the code (looking for translations) that is slowing it down. LinqKit didn't make a difference.